# Device ####### lost during operation install for message ######

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm running a project in {N} 5.1.0. Recently I've been having a semi-recurring issue when attempting to run on a physical device using `tns run ios`. The error message is:

> Unable to apply changes on device:  path/to/project/platforms/ios/build/device/funfanglemobilepos.ipa on device with identifier undefined. Error is: Device 00008020-000418E936D8002E lost during operation install for message 53e1b992-66b6-41f8-96bf-c81b74d63915.

It works fine when I run directly from Xcode or when I run on an emulator and it doesn't always happen. Sometimes I'll be able to run on my physical device and it will get this error when I change some code.

I've run `tns doctor` and it seems like everything is fine with my setup. Any ideas?

Comment: If it is iphoneXR or the other newer one, try to change the usb cable provided with the same. I have faced the same issue but changing cable solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to try a different cable, just like Narendra commented above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a working cable (it was working a few minutes before the error).

The solution was to restart my iPhone. Don't know what happened though.